# Python - extracting data from JSON response (using TomTom api)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tomtom

I'm trying to retrieve information on route times using the [TomTom API](https://developer.tomtom.com/online-routing/online-routing-documentation-routing/calculate-route).

By providing the API url, an API key ([that you can get by registering](https://developer.tomtom.com/user/register)) and a source and destination latitude/longitude I want to return the travel time.

I thought that I was getting a dictionary of dictionaries from the response, and should be able to access the data using - jsonTomTomString['routes']['summary']['travelTimeInSeconds’]

but I'm getting ...

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ConfigParser
import requests
import json
import sys
import time
import datetime

from urllib import urlopen

# URL to the tomtom api
apiURL      = "https://api.tomtom.com/routing/1/calculateRoute/"
# apiKey
apiKey      = "get this from link in description"

#[coordinates]
sourceLat   = 51.5560241
sourceLon   = -0.2817075
destLat     = 53.4630621
destLon     = -2.2935288

tomtomURL = "%s/%s,%s:%s,%s/json?key=%s" % (apiURL,sourceLat,sourceLon,destLat,destLon,apiKey)

getData = urlopen(tomtomURL).read()
jsonTomTomString = json.loads(getData)

totalTime = jsonTomTomString['routes']['summary']['totalTimeSeconds']

print ("time to destination is: ", totalTime)
```

The JSON response looks like this...

> {"formatVersion":"0.0.12","copyright":"Copyright 2018 TomTom
>   International BV. All rights reserved. This navigation data is the
>   proprietary copyright of TomTom International BV and may be used only
>   in accordance with the terms of a fully executed license agreement
>   entered into between TomTom International BV, or an authorised
>   reseller and yourself. If you have not entered into such a license
>   agreement you are not authorised to use this data in any manner and
>   should immediately return it to TomTom International
>   BV.","privacy":"TomTom keeps information that tells us how and when
>   you use our services. This includes information about the device you
>   are using and the information we receive while you use the service,
>   such as locations, routes, destinations and search queries. TomTom is
>   unable to identify you based on the information it collects, and will
>   not try to. TomTom uses the information for technical diagnostics, to
>   detect fraud and abuse, to create usage reports, and to improve its
>   services. The information is kept only for these purposes and for a
>   limited period of time, after which it is destroyed. TomTom applies
>   security methods based on industry standards to protect the
>   information against unauthorised access. TomTom will not give anyone
>   else access to the information or use it for any other purpose, unless
>   explicitly and lawfully ordered to do so following due legal process.
>   You can find out more at http://tomtom.com/privacy. You can contact
>   TomTom by going to
>   http://tomtom.com/support.","routes":[{"summary":{"lengthInMeters":326856,"travelTimeInSeconds":13018,"trafficDelayInSeconds":818,"departureTime":"2018-01-08T17:10:31Z","arrivalTime":"2018-01-08T20:47:28Z"},"legs":[{"summary":{"lengthInMeters":326856,"travelTimeInSeconds":13018,"trafficDelayInSeconds":818,"departureTime":"2018-01-08T17:10:31Z","arrivalTime":"2018-01-08T20:47:28Z"},"points":[{"latitude":51.55598,"longitude":-0.28216},{"latitude":51.55601,"longitude":-0.28292},{"latitude":51.55602,"longitude":-0.28384},{"latitude":51.55602,"longitude":-0.28395},{"latitude":51.55602,"longitude":-0.28442},{"latitude":51.55603,"longitude":-0.28493},{"latitude":51.55603,"longitude":-0.28564},{"latitude":51.55603,"longitude":-0.28611},

Grateful for help with getting this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a `[` after `"routes":`, so routes is an array.

Try `jsonTomTomString['routes'][0]['summary']['totalTimeSeconds']`

Comment: I also don't see 'totalTimeSeconds' in the JSON, unless it's somewhere after the cutoff.  So it should be `jsonTomTomString['routes'][0]['summary']['travelTimeInSeconds']`